# Questions on a Scrollbar's AdjustmentListener behavior

Tags: java, scrollbar, listener

I modified an exist JTable with Scrollbar example and added an Adjustment Listener and JMenu item for this example.

When the example is executed and the Frame resized affecting the scrollbar or if the scrollbar is moved, the listener is executed as expected. Accessing the menu on the toolbar will fire the Adjustment Listener.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class AdjustmentListener_Example3 
{
    static int x = 0;
    public static void main(String[] argv) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(data, col);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent event) 
            {
                x++;
                System.out.println(x + " : " + event.getValue());
                String type = null;
                switch (event.getAdjustmentType()) 
                {
                    case AdjustmentEvent.TRACK:
                        type = "Track";
                        break;
                     
                    case AdjustmentEvent.BLOCK_DECREMENT:
                        type = "Block Decrement";
                        break;
                     
                    case AdjustmentEvent.BLOCK_INCREMENT:
                        type = "Block Increment";
                        break;
                     
                    case AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_DECREMENT:
                        type = "Unit Decrement";
                        break;
                     
                    case AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_INCREMENT:
                        type = "Unit Increment";
                        break;
                  }
                  System.out.println("    Type: " + type);

            }
        });
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu"); 
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Send Action To Scrollbar");
        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    AdjustmentListener[] adjustmentListeners = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getAdjustmentListeners();
                    adjustmentListeners[0].adjustmentValueChanged(new AdjustmentEvent(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(), 0, 0, 0));
                }
            });
        menu.add(menuItem1); 
        menuBar.add(menu); 
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);         
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(20,20, 500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    static String [][] data = {{"001","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"002","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"003","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"004","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"005","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"006","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"007","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"008","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"009","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"010","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"011","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"012","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"013","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"014","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"015","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"016","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"017","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"018","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"019","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"020","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"021","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"022","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"023","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"024","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"025","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"026","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"027","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"028","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"},
               {"029","vinod","Bihar","India","Biology","65","First"},
               {"030","Raju","ABC","Kanada","Geography","58","second"},
               {"031","Aman","Delhi","India","computer","98","Dictontion"},
               {"032","Ranjan","Bangloor","India","chemestry","90","Dictontion"}};
    
    static String col[] = {"Roll","Name","State","country","Math","Marks","Grade"};
}
```

***Questions :***

Using a JButton, if no Listener is created nothing happens, but even if the AdjustmentListener was never added in this example, the scrollbars would work. This indicates the scrollbars already have a default listener to handle the functionality.

Is the Adjustment listener a means to add additional listeners to the scrollbar instead of overriding the existing one?

Is the Adjustment listener primarily to execute other non-scroll bar behavior anytime the scrollbar is moved?

Why isn't the @override annotation required along with a call to super within the custom listener?

Comment: *... This indicates the scrollbars already have a default listener to handle the functionality.* - you have it backwards. The scrollbars are not dependent on the AdjustmentListener. The scrolling logic will generate the AdjustmentEvent. The event just tells you that process has occured, it does not generate the processing. Same as a MouseEvent. The event just tells you that YOU moved the mouse. It does not move the mouse for you.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When working with the gui objects, is there a "rule" of sorts to determine if an object has a type of AdjustmentListener or if one must override the built-in functionality and make the super() call?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to know what listeners are available for a component, then read the API. You will see all the addXXX(...) methods. You don't use super() because you are not overriding any default behaviour. You are responding to an event to do your own custom processing. Read the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html) for working examples.

Comment: I could probably explain my question better but not in this limited space. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I will check out the link.